# Quasar Error on Android: webpage at ip:port could not be loaded because net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, quasar-framework

I am learning quasar and I created a new project using `quasar init name`. I then move into the new project root directory and ran `quasar mode -a cordova` to add a cordova project. I cd to src-cordova and run `cordova platform add android` and `cordova requirements`. No errors on the requirements check. I go back to the project root and run `quasar dev -m cordova -T android`. Its results in a empty page that says "webpage at ip:port could not be loaded because net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE". Running `quasar dev` works fine and `quasar dev -m electron` works as well.

[image]

When I install it on ios with `quasar dev -m cordova -T ios` I get a blank page. Also if I `cd` to the src-cordova directory I can manually install the starter cordova app on ios or android without issue. Why am I getting this error on android and a blank page on ios with just a default project?

Quasar version 0.17.18
Node version 8.12.0
Cordova version 8.0.0
NPM version 6.4.1
macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: So what options should I have for IP addresses when I run `quasar dev -m cordova -T android/ios`? I'm getting 10.1.2.150 and 169.254.112.9 to choose from. On Android if I choose the first IP I get this error but the app crashes for not finding assets if I choose the 2nd IP. On iOS I get the same issue, blank screen, no matter which IP I choose. However a co-worker has 192.168.0.4 and 169.254.230.96. Our first IP's are not even close to matching. Based on what my co-worker has I would think my choices should be 192.168.x.x or 169.254.x.x.

Comment: I just got word from someone on their discord that the development computer your working on must be on the same network or somehow pingable from your dev computer. My computer was not on the same network so i joined the network but I still cant ping my phone/tablet so I’m going investigate why. I’m guessing this will fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my most recent comment was correct. It is a requirement for the dev computer to be on the same network as the mobile device you wand to install the app on using `quasar dev -m cordova -T android/ios`. Once I got that set up and there was communication between my computer and the mobile devices, this problem went away.